# Getting data from DB from DB through Navigation Properties giving InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

i am trying to get data from 3 different tables. I want to calculate total purchasing and sales of each store. Currently my Order table have 0 records for some stores. i am getting this error .`

**System.InvalidOperationException: 'Nullable object must have a value.'**

`

```
 var stats = context.Stores.Select(s => new StoreStats()
        {
            //StoreID = s.store_id,
            //StoreName = s.StoreName + s.Ref_No,
            //RefNo = s.Ref_No,
            //MonthPurchasing = s.Purchasing != null ? s.Purchasing.Where(x => (x.Date - DateTime.Now).TotalDays <= 30).Sum(x => x.Amount) : 0,
            //MonthPurchasingCount = s.Purchasing != null ? s.Purchasing.Where(x => (x.Date - DateTime.Now).TotalDays <= 30).Count() : 0,
            //AverageMonthlyPurchasing = s.Purchasing != null ? s.Purchasing.Where(x => (x.Date - DateTime.Now).TotalDays <= 30).Count() / 30 : 0,
            //MonthSales = s.Order != null ? s.Order.Where(x => (x.Date - DateTime.Now).TotalDays <= 30).Sum(x => x.Amount) : 0,
            //MonthSalesCount = s.Purchasing != null ? s.Purchasing.Where(x => (x.Date - DateTime.Now).TotalDays <= 30).Count() : 0,
            //AverageMonthlySale = s.Order != null ? s.Order.Where(x => (x.Date - DateTime.Now).TotalDays <= 30).Count() / 30 : 0,
            //MonthlyProfit = (s.Purchasing != null ? s.Purchasing.Where(x => (x.Date - DateTime.Now).TotalDays <= 30).Sum(x => x.Amount) : 0) - (s.Order != null ? s.Order.Where(x => (x.Date - DateTime.Now).TotalDays <= 30).Sum(x => x.Amount) : 0),
            TotalPurchasing = s.Purchasing != null ? s.Purchasing.Sum(x => x.Amount) : 0,
            TotalSales = s.Order != null ? s.Order.Sum(x => x.Amount) : 0,
            TotalProfit = s.Purchasing != null ? s.Purchasing.Sum(x => x.Amount) - s.Order.Sum(x => x.Amount) : 0,
            //CompletedOrders = s.Order != null ? s.Order.Where(x => x.status == Model.Order.Status.Completed).Count() : 0,
            //PendingOrders = s.Order != null ? s.Order.Where(x => x.status == Model.Order.Status.Pending).Count() : 0,
            //TotalEmployees = s.Employees != null ? userManager.Users.Where(x => x.store_id != null && x.store_id == s.store_id).Count() : 0,
            //TotalBrands = s.Stock != null ? s.Stock.Where(x => x.store_id == s.store_id).Count() : 0,
        }).ToList();
        d.Stores = stats;
```

**Edit**: After Hard Debugging it is found that the line which is non-commented throwing this  exception

Comment: Will you include your StoreStats and Purchasing class? Thanks.

Comment: I would say first check your query on SQL server if it is correct and return you expected result. Create your result set empty first then get your query and fill the result set. Exception is just saying that you have a field that is nullable but you are trying to access it as non nullable. Maybe filter your stores to not include in select if they have purchasing set to null.

Comment: you are checking for  s.Order != null  but in the last line you are going for  s.Order.Sum without any such checks !! I would say perhaps there is a problem in that part !!

Comment: well i coverted the totalsales to totalAnualSale like this   s.Purchasing != null ? s.Purchasing.Where(x=> (x.Date - DateTime.Now).TotalDays <= 360). Sum(x => x.Amount) : 0, and it start working. i dont understand why its not working with overall records